# Powershell: Different behaviour Github Actions vs Gitub Codespace (Cannot find type: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded)

Tags: powershell, .net-core, github-actions

there is this NET8 `crypto.dll` class lib I need to build and use in an Github Actions workflow. But for the love of god, I cannot make it work with Powershell (core).

The runner runs on an Ubuntu VM, the class lib is published using this step:

```yaml
name: workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    paths: 
      - folder/prefix__**.json

permissions:
  id-token: write

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Prepare
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x.x'

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet publish ./crypto/crypto.csproj --configuration Release --nologo -r linux-x64

      - name: Authenticate
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      - name: Transfer
        run: ./upload.ps1
        shell: pwsh
```

This completes ok and publishes the `./crypto/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/publish/crypto.dll` which I now need to use in a script `upload.ps1`. Now when I, interactively, run the following either locally (Win) or a (linux-based) dev container in Github codespace, it works fine. I can instantiate the type in the class lib.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path "./crypto/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/publish/crypto.dll"))
$crypto = New-Object -TypeName MyNamespace.ClassName -ArgumentList $text
```

Locally (Win)

```
PS C:\Users\me\src\sql> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path "./crypto/bin/Release/net8.0/publish/crypto.dll").Path)

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Users\me\src\sql\crypto\bin\Release\net8.0\publish\crypto.dll

PS C:\Users\me\src\sql> $crypto = New-Object -TypeName MyNamespace.ClassName -ArgumentList $text
PS C:\Users\me\src\sql>
```

Remote (Github codespace)

```bash
root@codespaces-164733:/workspaces/sql# pwsh
PowerShell 7.4.0
PS /workspaces/sql> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path "./crypto/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/publish/crypto.dll"))

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     /workspaces/sql/crypto/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/publish/crypto.dll

PS /workspaces/sql> $crypto = New-Object -TypeName MyNamespace.ClassName -ArgumentList $text                                             
PS /workspaces/sql>
```

However, when doing this as part of a Github Action, the instantiation fails. Here's an exerpt from the action run log. It loads the types from the assembly but just thereafter *still* fails to use them.

```bash
#...

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     /home/runner/work/sql/sql/crypto/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/publish/crypto.dll
New-Object: /home/runner/work/sql/sql/upload.ps1:29
Line |
  29 |  …   $crypto = New-Object -TypeName MyNamespace.ClassName -Argume …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find type [MyNamespace.ClassName]: verify that the
     | assembly containing this type is loaded.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

#...
```

I am at a complete loss why this is, I even tried having the workflow run in a Windows-runner, but even there it's the same.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Any insights or feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include the rest of your workflow in your question.

Comment: Edited question to include workflow yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings to check:

- Can you confirm the environment is closely replicated? This includes the operating system, .NET version, and any dependencies your library might have.
- Based on the error `MyNamespace.ClassName` is not loaded. Check the path of the DLL in the GitHub Action environment. It’s possible that the path might be different in the GitHub Action environment compared to your local environment or GitHub Codespace.
- Confirm that GitHub Action has the necessary permissions to access and execute the DLL file.
- Add some more logging to pinpoint where else failures are occurring/get more detailed logging.

Comment: Hi, so at least my local env is not the same (Win), as for the ones managed by Github I cannot say, might be. The dll path is perfectly fine. I also tried `chmod +x` to the dll, which didnt help. To be honest, this ate so much of my time, I just created a new console app project referencing the class lib and just executing that with dotnet run in the workflow, which worked perfectly ok. Still, annoying that I needed to include another project in the solution.